# How to allow device to support allocations for both RX_DIGITIZER and RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER?

Tags: c++, redhawksdr

I'm using CentOS 6.6 (64-bit) and RH 1.10.2

I have a waveform that requires a `FRONTEND::TUNER` device that is of type `RX_DIGITIZER`. I also have a 1.10.2 based device that is a `RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER`. This device has all the functionality that the waveform needs, but the waveform will not use it because of the different tuner type.

I see that it is not picked because `FrontendTunerDevice<TunerStatusStructType>::allocateCapacity()` (in `fe_tuner_device.cpp`) that my device inherits looks for an exact match on `tuner_type`.

I'm not seeing any elegant ways around this. Here are the two not so elegant ways I can see around it.

I can either completely override `allocateCapacity` and duplicate 95% of its logic, but explicitly accept both tuner types.

Or I can override `allocateCapacity` and modify the capabilities before passing to the superclass method. In pseudo-code:

```
CORBA::Boolean MyDevice::allocateCapacity(const CF::Properties & capacities)
{
   if ( capacities ask for RX_DITIGIZER ) {
      CF::Properties caps = capacities;
      change type to RX_DITIGIZER_CHANNELIZER
      return super::allocateCapacity(caps);
   } else {
      return super::allocateCapacity(capacities);
   }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The FrontEnd interfaces specification as outlined in Appendix E of the REDHAWK User Manual is a guide and has been known to be interpreted in different ways by REDHAWK device developers.  In your case, the simplest solution would be to change the allocation in your waveform to an RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER and connect a listener to the device, assuming the device has the ability to output wideband data (RX_DIGITIZER).  Otherwise, your suggested approach is correct while keeping in mind that the device must perform the appropriate bookkeeping should a user allocated DDCs against the CHANNELIZER portion of this device.

For more information, please refer to section E.2 on Frontend Tuner Types.